# Where can I EV train with Hordes in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm starting to get my competitive Pokemon team together and would I like to EV train using hordes like in XY.

Which routes give the highest Pokemon encounter rate for each stat, and which Pokemon should I be battling?

Comment: Is there an advantage to using Horde battles for EV training over using Super Training?

Comment: @ShadowZ. - It's quicker. In one battle I can have as much as 50evs awarded (10 Per Pokemon with Power items and pokerus) and with a reasonably powerful spread move its over in 20 seconds. Super training is good for finishing off any of those more precise sets, but isn't good at applying a lot of EVs really quickly

Comment: Plus the fact I can EV train multiple Pokemon at once, allowing me to setup duplicate copies easily for different movessets or for trading with friends

Comment: Ah, I usually just super train cause it is straightforward and simple.

Comment: @ShadowZ. - I used to as well, and theres nothing wrong with that way either, its just slow. In 5 battles I can have put 250EVs into a stat on 5 different Pokemon (the sixth being the 'trainer' with Sweet Scent and Spread moves) - compared with 21 Super Training battles to reach 252 for one Pokemon . And thats 21 assuming only doing the Level 3, 12 point battle, which is harder to complete when you have less EVs because you do less damage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the use of Sweet Scent to attract hordes, these locations have a 100% Encounter chance (or add up to 100%) for the horde Pokemon and the respective stat:

| Stat | Location | Pokemon | Pokemon Level | EVs per battle | % Chance to Encounter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP | Rusturf Tunnel | Whismur | 5 | 5 HP | 100% |
| Attack | Mt. Pyre | Shuppet | 15 | 5 Atk | 100% |
| Defense | Route 111 | Sandshrew | 11 | 5 Def | 100% |
| Special Attack | Routes 113 or 119 | Spinda or Oddish | 13 (Oddish), 9 (Spinda) | 5 SpA | 100% |
| Special Defense | Route 115 | Swablu | 10 | 5 SpD | 100% |
| Speed | Route 104 | Zigzagoon, Wingull or Taillow | 2 | 5 Spe | 100% |

#### Other Considerations:

- Sweet Scent/Honey actually work in overworld Sandstorm/Rain unlike in previous games
- Shuppet Appears in the Cemetery Area of Mt Pyre
- Petaburg Woods divides Route 104 in two. (North – Wingull, South – Taillow)
- Pokérus will double the EVs gained, and stacks with the items below:
- **Macho Brace** (Doubles total EVs gained) - Route 111
- **Power Items** - Battle Resort

  - *Anklet* (+4 Speed per Pokemon defeated)
  - *Band*  (+4 Sp. Def per Pokemon defeated)
  - *Belt*  (+4 Defense per Pokemon defeated)
  - *Bracer* (+4 Attack per Pokemon defeated)
  - *Lens*  (+4 Sp. Attack per Pokemon defeated)
  - *Weight* (+4 HP per Pokemon defeated)

#### Sources:

- [Nugget Bridge](http://nuggetbridge.com/articles/ev-training-horde-hotspots-pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/)
- [iDigitalTimes](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/pokemon-omega-ruby-and-alpha-sapphire-ev-training-tips-and-tricks-make-your-mon-best-397085)
- [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/hordes.shtml)

Answer (score 5):

For a higher EV yield, you can use the following areas for 2EV points per Pokemon (10 per battle, 20 with Pokerus and 40 with Macho Brace+Pokerus per battle)

**Skypillar**

- Ariados - *2 ATK*
- Golbat - *2 SPD*

**Victory Road**

- Loudred - *2 HP*

**Route 117**

- Roselia - *2 Sp.ATK*

**Route 113**

- Skarmory - *2 DEF*

And haven't found one with 2 Sp.DEF yet. These aren't guaranteed to be the only hordes on those routes though, just a huge yield imo.

The ones in sky pillar are very common. There is one additional horde of Swablu, but it's uncommon and it usually alternates between Ariados and Golbat. The Loudred in Victory Road seems to be rare, so Whismur might be the better option. Skarmory on Route 113 is relatively rare; almost all the time you get Spinda instead. I haven't tried for Roselia yet: I don't imagine it's that rare since it's abundant on its route in the first place. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice. Are they the 'common' horde encounter though? (I.e. there'd be little point if you had to run from 10 hordes to get a Skarmory horde for example) :)